# Colorbox (jQuery image gallery plugin) issues in IE

Tags: jquery, html, css, colorbox

I want to use Colorbox ( http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/ ) in my project, but it has some issues in IE. My bug report can be found here: https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/issues/104 (nobody answers).

In brief, it looks like image corners are positioned incorrectly (though the shift is just 1px), just look at this picture http://s51.radikal.ru/i132/1107/95/0d0e02605366.jpg and you will understand what I mean. This problem occurs only in IE (I tested in IE8 & IE9, but it seems same problem exists in IE6 ad presumably in IE7).

The problem can also be viewed here (in IE, of course):
http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example1/index.html
and here:
http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example3/index.html

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed controls.png from example1 theme (added 4 transparent lines) and now it is looks better in IE.
The changed controls.png can be found here:
http://www.mediafire.com/?h8eqdg3mcums9ye
or here:
http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/251196/controls.png

Another thing that helps is to set maxWidth and scalePhotos = true, then the problem is almost not noticeable. I used 807 for maxWidth in my case. (checked it on 2 different PCs).

The best result is when I combine the changed controls.png with setting maxWidth & scalePhotos.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/#paths ?

Comment: Yes, I did... In fact, the problem can be viewed on their examples page: http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example1/index.html